# Установка и запуск AVR-Doper на Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows-10, avr

Не могу найти/установить драйвер на программатор. В диспечере ошибка:

> Error 10` (невозможно запустить устройство).

Кто с таким сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте последний драйвер для устройства.
Распакуйте архиватором, например 7zip.
В диспетчере устройств выберете "Обновить драйвер" и укажите папку с распакованным драйвером.

Comment: мне еще помогало отключение защиты разделением памяти в виндоуз дефендере. с включенной опцией у меня не работал драйвер осциллографа после обновления с одной из версий десятки на другую.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/4096339/windows-10-device-security-in-windows-security вот ссылка на статью от MS, старые драйвера бывает с этой опцией конфликтуют.